# Debugging raytracer scene output

Tags: graphics, raytracing

I'm writing a raytracer and need something to debug it with.

I found [this](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse557/09au/projects/trace/extra/debug.html) but alas, the source is not publicly available it seems.

Is there anything similar out there?

EDIT: Developing on linux with straight C, but i have access to all major OSs and IDEs - Visual studio, emacs, Xcode, etc. I'm well experienced with all major programming languages.

Comment: Please provide more info. Which language are you using? On which platform/OS? Are you using a development environment?

Comment: Please add your own description for the kind of debugging facility you're interested in, rather than relying solely on the link.  Without such a description, your question may be confusing to the casual observer -- more difficult to answer constructively, and less useful to others who might have the same problem.

Comment: hello @meht , its been 10 years were you able to find a good debugger ?

Answer (score 0):

The link from the question appears to be an interactive ray-visualizer for a university ray tracer.  Basically, it provides (on demand) information for individual rays, including a 3D sketch of the ray path itself.

Unfortunately, if you're writing your own ray tracer from scratch, you're unlikely to be able to effectively take advantage of someone else's ray-visualizer -- that kind of application-specific facility tends to be specific to the framework it's intended to debug.

If this kind of facility is important to you, it would probably be easiest to start with a ray tracing framework which includes the ray-visualizer already, and implement your ray tracing project in that context.

On the other hand, if you are already familiar with conventional 3D graphics, it might not be too difficult to write such a ray-visualizer yourself.